# How to get stdout instead of debug output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getElements(arr, queries):
    size = arr[0]
    newarray = []
    subarray = []

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        subarray.append(arr[i])
        if(i % size == 0):
            newarray.append(subarray)
            subarray = []
    print("results are :")
    for q in queries:
        print((newarray[q[0] - 1])[q[1] - 1])
    
n = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(int(input()))
queries = [[3, 2], [2, 1]]
getElements(arr, queries)
```

The output is 10 and 5, which is correct in my code, but I dont know how to get it as a normal output instead of debug output.

Comment: What do you mean by `debug output` ?

Comment: I use the Print ("results are :") code to print the results, but now my output states: debug output results are: 10, 5. which is correct, but i would like it to show in a better way

Comment: What I actually mean is that I want a stdout instead of a debug output

Comment: @Charles That's not coming from Python. Are you running your code in an IDE?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, but it doesn't accept my code somehow

Comment: @Charles Which IDE? Please add its tag, e.g. [tag:vscode]